# Using MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey on the top level menu items

Tags: wpf, menuitem

It seems that the style of the top level `MenuItem` UIElements is different than the lower level MenuItems. I would like to use the same style on the top level as the sub levels. How can I replace the style of the top level with that of the sub level?

I see there is a resourcekey for both styles...
`MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey` and `MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Controltemplate for targettype of menuitem and use it for both:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyMenuItemTemplateKey" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Grid Name="Border" Height="25">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Name="BorderIcon" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <ContentPresenter Name="Icon" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
        </Border>
        <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Margin="10,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
        <Border Name="BorderChecked" Grid.Column="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="Transparent" Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
        <Border Name="BorderDisable" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="BorderChecked" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="BorderDisable" Property="Background" Value="#3FFFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the make a style where you define both templates with the same templatekey:

```
<Style x:Key="MyMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8.5pt"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyMenuItemTemplateKey}"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyMenuItemTemplateKey}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Nawed. Could I skip creating the ControlTemplate and just use SubmenuItemTemplateKey in place of MyMenuItemTemplateKey for both top and sub templates?

Comment: I tried your solution but the menu is displayed as before, with both top and sub menus using different styles.

Comment: Maybe we should turn it around, and could you please explain exactly what you want to achieve ?  You  could also have a look at the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for more info. It's pretty simple you create one style for the whole menuitem, and 4 item templates, one for each scenario: TopLevelHeader, TopLevelItem, SubmenuHeader, SubmenuItem. The idea is that you will have icons and shortcut link in the submenues but not in the topmenu.

Comment: Hi, to rephrase what I have mentioned, I would like the style of the top level items to be the same style as used in the sub menu items. Yes, I suppose I could write many lines of ControlTemplate xaml and I'm sure that would work. However, I would like to think there is a solution where I do not have to rewrite the styles. Since I have MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey... there ought to be some way of assigning this to MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey.